# htaccess block everything but index.php and folder public and files in it

Tags: .htaccess

I'm kinda new to htaccess, I'm trying to block everything but index.php, the folder public and the files it contain. I have googled around and got this so far. Its kinda working but it looks like the webserver dont have access to the files either. It opens index.php but no css,js or php files are included. I can also go to domain.com/folder/ and get to the index page but its empty i would want it to redirect to index.php if possible. And i also have no clue about how to open the public folder while everything else above is set.

```
AuthType Basic
order allow,deny
<Files ~ "^(index\.php|)$">
  Allow from all
</Files>
<Files .htaccess>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all of your code with this `mod_rewrite` rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:index\.php$|public/|.+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|ico|tiff|css|js)$) [NC]
RewriteRule . - [F]
```

This rule will block everything except `public/` folder, `index.php` or any other file ending with .css, .js, images etc.

Comment: It works but, domain.com do not send me to index.php but to gives me access denied and my server can still not use the php files when its set so the index file cant load its functions

Comment: Try my updated rule to allow `domain.com`. However I don't understand next comment. Clarify with examples.